# NHibernate 2 + NHibernate.JetDriver + MS Access: how to access 'attachment' field of table

Tags: nhibernate, ms-access, ms-jet-ace, attachment-field

This is my first question on StackOverflow!

I am using NHibernate 2 in my vb.net project 
I also use NHibernate.JetDriver to access a MS Access database

I have a table named tblPeople and it has a field named 'PersonImage' witch it is of the 'attachment' field type

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
    namespace="BusinessModel" assembly="NHibernateDemo">
  <class name="clsPeople" table="tblPeople">
    <id name="ID">
      <column name="[ID]" sql-type="int" not-null="true" />
    </id>
    ....
    <property name="Image">
      <column name="[PersonImage]" sql-type="ntext/nvarchar/varbinary/?????"   />
      <!--varbinary(max)-->
    </property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Here is the class

```
Namespace BusinessModel

    Public Class clsPeople 

       Public Overridable Overloads Property ID() As Integer


       Public Overridable Overloads Property Image() As [byte()/String/String/**?????**]

    End Class

End Namespace
```

Any Ideas on what data types to choose for the mappings in order to get the actual images from the table ?

Any help in the right direction will make me huppy!

I even tried with a hibernate 3 and Custom Compilled JetDriver but i also whatever i do i keep getting errors 
Could not cast the value in field column of type String to the Type BinaryBlobType or Byte[] or whatever
except if i put String where i get a ; seperated list of filenames but nothing more!

Comment: i found this but i do not get it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141149/nhibernate-lazy-loaded-properties

Comment: i also found this but i do not understand if i should use it http://www.martinwilley.com/net/code/nhibernate/usertype.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to specify sql-type unless it is really necessary. Instead you can specify the "type" as "String" or "AnsiString".

Secondly I highly recommend you to use the last version (3.3.3 as of this moment) of NHibernate. Also you can consider other mapping types like Mapping By Code or attributes (but stay away from fluent :)
PS. I found your question from freenode IRC

Comment: The tricky thing is here how to convert from string to image ? I am not sure on how to compile the jetdriver with the 3.3.3 version but i am now downloading the repositories to find out.

Comment: i compiled the latest nhebernate 3.3.3GA with the JetDriver with no luck either. whatever i do i keep getting errors "Could not cast the value in field column of type String to the Type BinaryBlobType" or "Byte[]" or "whatever" except if i put String where i get a ; seperated list of filenames but nothing more!   seems that this happens : http://stackoverflow.com//questions/6895523/need-c-sharp-code-for-reading-multiple-attachments-from-microsoft-access-attachm

Answer (score 0):

ok i think i am close enough!

i use this property in my hbm.xml

```
  <property name="FileData">
      <column name="Image.FileData" />
    </property>
```

i use this property in my class clsPeople

> Private _FileData As Byte()
>           Public Overridable Overloads Property FileData As Byte()
>               Get
>                   Return _FileData
>               End Get
>               Set(value As Byte())
>
> ```
>             If value IsNot Nothing Then
>
>                 Try
>                     'get offset to data
>                     Dim offsetbytes As Byte()
>                     offsetbytes = SubArray(Of Byte)(value, 0, 4)
>
>                     Dim offset = BitConverter.ToInt32(offsetbytes, 0)
>                     Console.WriteLine("offset : " & offset)
>
>                     Dim headerBytes() As Byte = SubArray(Of Byte)(value, 0, offset)
>                     'Dim allbytes() As Byte = CType(value, Byte())
>                     Dim header = BitConverter.ToString(headerBytes, 0)
>
>                     Dim databytes(0 To (value.Length - offset) - 1) As Byte
>                     Array.ConstrainedCopy(value, offset, databytes, 0, value.Length - offset)
>                     Dim img As Image = ObjToImg(databytes)
>                     img.Save("c:\" & Κωδικός_Ακινήτου & ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg)
>                 Catch ex As Exception
>
>                 End Try
>
>             End If
>             _FileData = value
>         End Set
>     End Property
> ```

i will keep you posted on how this works on one / more than one attached files